# Remote Mysql connection issue with 3306 port opened

Tags: mysql, mariadb, port, ipv6

I know this may seems like an already seen issue but I searched all over the internet and did not found a situation being exactly like mine

I am developping a JavaFX app using a remote MariaDB database located on a VPS. It used to work fine but now it doesn't. To track the issue, I tried to come back to the basics and access my database remotely from my terminal. Here is the issue : it does not work anymore. I only get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.110.XX.XX' (115)` and basically a timeout error with my telnet.

I can access my database from within the VPS without any issue and my VPS has no firewall (I know, bad practice) and a 3306 port openned (`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` gives the following)

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2705239/systemd-res
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      271/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      704/exim4
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      467941/java
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      2704768/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      467941/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      337/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      271/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      704/exim4
```

As you can see, my issue seems not to be related to a bound address as I could read on all the internet. From my local computer, I can `ssh` to my VPS but cannot use the port 3306 to access to `mysql` remotely even tough my firewall has been completely shut down. I tried to use `telnet` with the port 3306 and even that gives me a timeout whereas it works perfectly with the port 22.

Basically, the two main ideas I found on the internet was paying attention to the bounded port and ensuring the firewalls were not active. As I already checked that, I am quite out of ideas. Would any of you have any lead?

Comment: `192.110.XX.XX` is not an IPV6 address but you are listening only on an IPV6 Address

Answer (score 2):

As clearly seen from your screenshot you have opened port 3306 on ipv6 address, not ipv4.

And you are trying to reach it on ipv6. It is not works that way.

You have options

- use ipv6 for connect
- disable ivp6 and check again
- put exact bind IP in MySQL config.